# Java stream giving syntax error in case of reduce operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use reduce methods on a stream of Integer to get sum of all values. but getting syntax error and not able to figure out the error.

```
List<Integer> ee = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f3 = x -> x / 2;
BinaryOperator<? extends Integer> accumulator = (x, y) -> x + y;
ee.stream().map(f3).reduce(new Integer(0), accumulator);
```

It gives error :

```
The method reduce(capture#2-of ? extends Integer, BinaryOperator<capture#2-of ? extends Integer>) in the type Stream<capture#2-of ? extends Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, BinaryOperator<capture#7-of ? extends Integer>)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with all the bounds you've got there. While it would take me a while to work out (and then explain) *exactly* what the compiler thinks is going on, it's much simpler if you just change everything to use the concrete type... after all, it's not like this is really a stream of "things that extend integer, but we're not sure what". They're just integers. This code compiles fine, and is also much simpler to understand.

```java
Function<Integer, Integer> f3 = x -> x / 2;
BinaryOperator<Integer> accumulator = (x, y) -> x + y;
int result = ee.stream().map(f3).reduce(Integer.valueOf(0), accumulator);
```

As noted in comments, autoboxing and the use of a method reference can simplify the last line significantly (and remove the need for the `accumulator` variable):

```java
int result = ee.stream().map(f3).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

The first snippet retains more of the structure of the question so that it's easier to adapt for other accumulator functions.

Comment: The declaration of `reduce` as`T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`  must be causing it to fail for the inference of the type when `new Integer(0)` is not something that defines `? extends Integer` I would guess.

Comment: @Naman: Something like that, yes. Given that the code that compiles is also easier to read, I'm not going to peek behind the curtain too much :)

Comment: It’s actually very simple. A declaration like `BinaryOperator<? extends Integer> accumulator` specifies that the input type is *unknown*. All we know, is that it is some subtype of `Integer`, but we don’t know which, which makes this function entirely unusable. The other function follows the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488) which is fine, but the compiler needs a little help like `.<Integer>map(f3)`. By the way, there’s no need for manual boxing, `reduce(0, accumulator)` or just `reduce(0, Integer::sum)` would do.

Comment: @Holger: I originally used 0 instead of `Integer.valueOf(0)`, but I wanted to keep it closer to the original code, without the deprecation warning.